# Using query results from one table in the SELECT list for another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

#### t1

```
campaign_name col_name
camp_1        col_1
camp_2        col_2
```

#### t2

```
col_1 col_2 col_3
 1      2     3
 2      4     6
 3      6     9
 4      8    12
```

I want to create a statement to use results from `t1` in the SELECT list for `t2` and show `t2` results.

Example:

Step 1: get results from table 1

```
select col_name from t1 where campaign_name = 'camp_1'
```

Result: `col_1`

Step 2: Use the result (`col_1`) for t2 and show the corresponding results

```
select col_1 from t2
```

The end results should be

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Just use a bunch of `case` expressions `case t1.col_name when 'col_1' then t2.col_1 when 'col_2' then t2.col_2 ... end`

Comment: @Charlieface This looks like example data. What if the real data has many more columns?

Comment: Then I would consider changing the schema, as mentioned by @slartidan I rarely see wide tables which actually make sense anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Consider to change your schema to something like this:

#### t1 (unchanged)

```
campaign_name col_name
camp_1        col_1
camp_2        col_2
```

#### t2

```
group_name col_name num
group1     col_1      1
group1     col_2      2
group1     col_3      3
group2     col_1      2
group2     col_2      4
group2     col_3      6
group3     col_1      3
group3     col_2      6
group3     col_3      9
group4     col_1      4
group4     col_2      8
group4     col_3     12
```

You can then select:

```
SELECT num
FROM t1
  JOIN t2 ON t1. col_name = t2. col_name
WHERE t1.campaign_name = 'camp_1'
```

Benefits:

- The SQL-Server can optimize your query, which makes it *faster*
- Use *single SQL* to query both tables
- You can define more *sophisticated* statements, by combining conditions for both tables at once

---

If you cannot change your schema, there is still a possibility to select the values without dynamic SQL. You can use the elaboratet feature `UNPIVOT` - which converts data from several columns into data in additional rows.

```
WITH unpivot_t2 AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM   t2
    UNPIVOT  
      (value FOR col_name IN (col_1, col_2, col_3))
    AS unpvt
)
SELECT value
FROM unpivot_t2
JOIN t1 ON t1.col_name = unpivot_t2.col_name
WHERE campaign_name = 'camp_1'
```

With this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    campaign_name varchar(255),
    col_name varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
    ('camp_1', 'col_1'),
    ('camp_2', 'col_2')

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    col_1 varchar(255),
    col_2 varchar(255),
    col_3 varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES
    (1,2,3),
    (2,4,6),
    (3,6,9),
    (4,8,12)
```

[Give it a try online!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8d813/15/0)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change your schema as ***slartidan*** said.
Then, first, you have to get your required column name(s) from the table, **t1**.

**Way One (Using SQL Concatenation)**

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @Columns = @Columns + col_name + ','
FROM t1
WHERE campaign_name = 'camp_1'
GROUP BY col_name
SET @Columns = LEFT(@Columns,LEN(@Columns)-1)
```

**Way Two (Using FOR XML PATH):**

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @Columns = STUFF((SELECT ',' + col_name
FROM t1
WHERE campaign_name = 'camp_1'
GROUP BY col_name
FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')
```

Then you have to execute a raw SQL.

```
EXEC ('SELECT ' + @Columns + ' FROM t2')
```

Hope, Then you can get dynamic column values from your desired table, **t2**.